# Facing problems with angular deployment in gh pages

Tags: angular, git, deployment, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

I recently deployed my app on gh pages, but i am facing a lot of troubles with 404 messages. The problems go from images not loading to pages disapearing, and i don't know what to do about it. Here is my app: [Dragon app](https://juli0o79.github.io/Dragon-project/list). The button at the end should open a new page but it doesn't work. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this url, its working fine

https://juli0o79.github.io/Dragon-project/create

You have added base-href, so the related operation should updated with relative url in your code. Update in necessary place.